# How to get the old Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate

Google Translate changed so when you double-click on the translated text it will make it editable so you can change it if there is something wrong with the translation.

The problem is I am used to double-clicking to select all the text and copy it. This option makes it difficult for me to select and copy. (I am aware that there is a button to select all the text.)

I've been translating this way for 3 years and I can't change it, and I also use it a lot.

It will be a great help if you can tell me how I can get the old style back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt you can actually get exactly the old interface, Google may already remove the code altogether. However you can get something close by disabling JavaScript for the page, you can easily double-click the translated text to select it, as shown in the image below:

[image: Screenshot of Google Translate without JavaScript]

Alternatively, even without disabling JavaScript you can do the selection with just an additional double click. Once you double click on the translated text and given chance to edit, you can instead select the text and ignore the editing form.